# Making conn.assigns available in multiple Phoenix views/templates

Tags: token, elixir, phoenix-framework

I need a user authentication token defined in the `SessionController`to be available in `layout/app.html.eex`.

My SessionController defines a token and assigns it to a `conn`.

```
token = Phoenix.Token.sign(conn, "user socket", user)

assign(conn, :user_token, token)
```

Then when I try to use the token in `app.html.eex` like the following,

```
 <script>window.userToken = "<%= assigns[:user_token] %>"</script>

or

 <script>window.userToken = "<%= @user_token %>"</script>
```

I get this error: `(ArgumentError) assign @user_token not available in eex template.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`conn.assigns` are reset on every request. If you want to store something in `SessionController` and have it available in future requests, you can use `put_session`;

In your SessionController:

```
token = Phoenix.Token.sign(conn, "user socket", user)
conn
|> put_session(:user_token, token)
|> render(...)
```

Then, to access it in other controllers, you can use:

```
token = get_session(conn, :user_token)
```

To access it in multiple templates, you can then add a plug to the appropriate pipeline(s) in your Router:

```
pipeline :browser do
  ...
  plug :fetch_user_token
end

...

def fetch_user_token(conn, _) do
  conn
  |> assign(:user_token, get_session(conn, :user_token))
end
```

Now you can access the token in any template with `@user_token` (or `assigns[:user_token]` or `assigns.user_token` or `@conn.assigns[:user_token]` or `@conn.assigns.user_token`; all will give the same result here).