# unable to persist session token in phoenix elixir app

Tags: session, authentication, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to create a custom server side User authentication for my application. With this I mean I save sessions with a field `token` and a field `user_id` on database and intend to keep that token accessible in `conn.assigns` as long as the session takes place. This last part is were I'm finding problems. Should say I'm a ruby developer and this is my first application in elixir.

Here's my Session model:

```
defmodule Prode.Session do
  use Prode.Web, :model

  schema "sessions" do
    field :token, :string
    belongs_to :user, Prode.User

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:user_id])
    |> validate_required([:user_id])
  end

  def create_changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
    |> changeset(params)
    |> put_change(:token, SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64())
  end

end
```

And here it's correspondent controller:

```
defmodule Prode.SessionController do
  use Prode.Web, :controller

  import Comeonin.Bcrypt, only: [checkpw: 2, dummy_checkpw: 0]

  alias Prode.Session
  alias Prode.User

  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    user = Repo.get_by(User, email: user_params["email"])

    cond do
      user && checkpw(user_params["password"], user.password_hash) ->
        session_changeset = Session.create_changeset(%Session{}, %{user_id: user.id})
        {:ok, session} = Repo.insert(session_changeset)
        conn
        |> assign(:token, session.token)
        |> put_status(:created)
        |> render("show.json", session: session)
      user ->
        conn
        |> put_status(:unauthorized)
        |> render("error.json", user_params)
      true ->
        dummy_checkpw
        conn
        |> put_status(:unauthorized)
        |> render("error.json", user_params)
    end
  end
end
```

Then I created the following plug to confirm authentication and set current user:

```
defmodule Prode.Authentication do
  import Plug.Conn
  alias Prode.{Repo, User, Session}
  import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 2]

  def init(options), do: options

  def call(conn, _opts) do
    case find_user(conn) do
      {:ok, user} -> assign(conn, :current_user, user)
      _otherwise  -> auth_error!(conn)
    end
  end

  defp find_user(conn) do
    session = Repo.get(Session, conn.assigns.token)
    case Repo.get(User, session.user_id) do
      nil     -> :error
      session -> {:ok, session}
    end
  end

end
```

This plug I add on other controllers:

```
plug Prode.Authentication
```

But the problem is, after a user is correctly authenticated and the execution runs the plug, `conn.assigns` is empty:

```
key :token not found in: %{}
```

Comment: You need to use `put_session` if you want it to be available in future requests. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41073614/320615 for my answer to a very similar question.

Comment: thanks @Dogbert. I had to add `fetch_session` before but it worked

Comment: Yep, you need to add `plug :fetch_session` in the appropriate place in your Router if it's not already present so that Phoenix decodes/encodes session data automatically.